# The use no-null operator in Angular/Typescript is a good or bad practice?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have noticed today I could use non-null operator to avoid lots of validations in some methods in angular like this:

```
public showAlertHeader(account: Account): boolean {
    return account!.brownfieldState === this.PENDING || !(account!.address && account!.address!.id);
}
```

But then my tslint complained about using this, which I can configure to not complain, but I got curious to know if this is a good or bad practice at all...

Comment: If `Account` is nullable, why not check `if (account == null) return something_else;` before the other return? (so you don't need to use `!.`)

Comment: Yeah, I can do that too. But then I would have more code lets say...
So I guess your answer to the main question would be, this is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think better practice is to use [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) operator nowdays. 
Here's a simplified example

```
function isAdmin(user: { admin: boolean } | undefined): boolean {
    return user?.admin === true;
}

function isAdmin2(user: { admin: boolean } | undefined): boolean {
    return user!.admin === true;
}

console.log(isAdmin({admin: false})); // false
console.log(isAdmin({admin: true})); // true
console.log(isAdmin(undefined)); // false

console.log(isAdmin2({admin: false})); // false
console.log(isAdmin2({admin: true})); // true
console.log(isAdmin2(undefined)); // Runtime Error!
```

Comment: That seems a good way to validate parameters. I will check optional chaining doc. I appreciate your time.